# Unrecognized attribute 'multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' issue on different Windows

Tags: windows, wcf, web-services, windows-7, configuration

I have a project built with target platform 3.5. 
I deployed it:

- IIS 7
- Windows 7
- there is .NET 4 installed on machine
- Microsoft .NET Framework
  Version:2.0.50727.**4961** (from AppPool)
- ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.**4955**(from AppPool)

**Application failed.** Parser Error Message: **Unrecognized attribute 'multipleSiteBindingsEnabled'.** Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

**I installed SP1 for Windows 7** and now configuration is:

- IIS 7
- Windows 7
- there is .NET 4 installed on machine
- Microsoft .NET Framework
  Version:2.0.50727.**5444**(from AppPool)
- ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.**5420**(from AppPool)

and now **it works**.

Is this Windows 7 SP1 fix described somewhere? What about other Windows (XP, 2003, 2008 R2), is it some fix for them?

Comment: I'm also seeing this behavior.  It's odd that this is a .Net 4.0 feature but yet it works targeting .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is Application Pools. If the target .net framework is 4.0 on your Visual studio then convert the .net framework version from 2.0 to 4.0 in App pool. because when you host an application, by default it is set to version 2 in the pool. By clicking on the application pool which is for the app you can change the version to 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Since the attribute is only applicable to applications that target the .NET Framework 4.0, I would suggest removing it all together from your configuration. Even if you *could* find some notes buried in the documented SP1 release, it still does not help you any if you are targeting an older Framework like 3.5.

MSDN link describing 'multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' attribute and its support:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehostingenvironment.multiplesitebindingsenabled.aspx